# Find common items in multiple lists in C# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I searched, but I found only answers which related to two lists. But what about when they are more than two?

```
List 1 = 1,2,3,4,5
List 2 = 6,7,8,9,1
List 3 = 3,6,9,2,0,1
List 4 = 1,2,9,0,5
List 5 = 1,7,8,6,5,4
List 6 = 1
List 7 =
```

How to get the common items? as you can see one of them is empty, so the common will be empty, but I need to skip empty lists.

Comment: You can use `Intersect` for two list, then apply `Intersect` to a new list and to the result of the previous `Intersect` etc.

Comment: If you need to skip empty lists as in you don't want them to cause the results to be empty you can just do `Lists.Where(l => l.Any())` to filter it out.

Comment: I updated my answer. It can skip empty list and null now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var data = new [] {
    new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    new List<int> {6, 7, 8, 9, 1},
    new List<int> {3, 6, 9, 2, 0, 1},
    new List<int> {1, 2, 9, 0, 5},
    new List<int> {1, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4},
    new List<int> {1},
    new List<int> {},
    null
};

IEnumerable<int> temp = null;
foreach (var arr in data)
    if (arr != null && arr.Count != 0)
        temp = temp == null ? arr : arr.Intersect(temp);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var data = new List<List<int>> {
    new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    new List<int> {6, 7, 2, 8, 9, 1},
    new List<int> {3, 6, 9, 2, 0, 1},
    new List<int> {1, 2, 9, 0, 5},
    new List<int> {1, 7, 8, 6, 2, 5, 4},
    new List<int> {1, 7, 2}
};


List<int> res = data
    .Aggregate<IEnumerable<int>>((a, b) => a.Intersect(b))
    .ToList();
```

The type of Aggregate is explicitly given, otherwise aggregation of two Lists would have to be List too. It can be easily adapted to run in parallel:

```
List<int> res = data
    .AsParallel<IEnumerable<int>>()
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Intersect(b))
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Except... it does not run in parallel. The problem is operations on IEnumerable are deferred, so even if they are logically merged in parallel context, the actual merging occurs in the `ToList()`, which is single threaded. For parallel execution it would be better to leave IEnumerable and return to the Lists:

```
List<int> res = data
    .AsParallel()
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Intersect(b).ToList());
```

Comment: This is the simplest and most generic answer, uses Linq properly, and applies to a collection of lists, rather than just a fixed number of lists as many of the other answers give. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can chain `Intersect`:

```
List<int> List1 = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
List<int> List2 = new List<int> { 6, 7, 8, 9, 1 };
List<int> List3 = new List<int> { 3, 6, 9, 2, 0, 1 };
List<int> List4 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 9, 0, 5 };
List<int> List5 = new List<int> { 1, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4 };
List<int> List6 = new List<int> { 1 };

List<int> common = List1
  .Intersect(List2)
  .Intersect(List3)
  .Intersect(List4)
  .Intersect(List5)
  .Intersect(List6)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: how to skip the list which has no items?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a `HashSet`.  You can put the items of the first collection in the hash, then iterate each collection after the first and create an new hash that you add items from the current collection to if it's in the hash.  At the end you assign that common hash set to the overall one and break if it's every empty.  At the end you just return the overall hash set.

```
public IEnumerable<T> CommonItems<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> collections)
{
    if(collections == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collections));

    using(var enumerator = collections.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if(!enumerator.MoveNext())
            return Enumerable<T>.Empty();

        var overall = new HashSet<T>(enumerator.Current);
        while(enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var common = new HashSet<T>();
            foreach(var item in enumerator.Current)
            {
                if(hash.Contains(item))
                    common.Add(item);
            }

            overall = common;
            if(overall.Count == 0)
                break;
        }

        return overall;
    }
}
```

Comment: Enumerating IEnumerable twice is a bad habit. There is no guarantee you would get the same sequence every time, but your algorithm rely on that (in Skip(1)). There is even no guarantee it is possible to enumerate the sequence twice. And finally, multiple enumeration can be very expensive in some cases.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek True, so here's a version that uses the enumerator instead.