# Finding and counting common list elements across multiple lists in C#

Tags: c#

So I have a set of lists with no set quantity on how many lists I have.

```
List1 = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
List2 = {"b", "c", "d", "e"}
List3 = {"c", "d", "e", "f"}
.
.
.
Listn = {"g", "e", "a", "c"}
```

Each list will contain unique items and the individual lists can have a length in the 20 - 30 item range. I'm storing all the lists inside another list to allow for n lists.

```
ListOfLists = {List1, List2, List3, ..., Listn}
```

What would be the best way, in terms of least processing power used, to generate a list or array containing containing all the unique items contained in the ListOfLists and the number of times they appear?

In terms of outputs, I am thinking the best option would be a list of arrays containing the item and the count of times it appeared.

```
UniqueListItems = { {"a", 12}, {"b" ,3}, {"c", 18}, {"d", 15}, {"e", 5} }
```

Eventually I would like to sort the list by item occurrence and render the items out in descending count order.

```
Output:
c
d
a
e
b
```

I have tried doing this using several nested for and foreach loops, but the result is some rather clunky code. One of the limiting factors is that the only list to list operations I found work with a maximum of 2 lists, as opposed to n lists.

Are there ways of using in built C# List operations for n lists? If not, what would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: You might want to look at [Find common items in multiple lists in C# linq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45255495/215552) if you can use LINQ.

Comment: `ListOfLists.SelectMany( x => x).GroupBy ( x => x ).ToDictionary( x => x.Key, x => x.Count );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Linq` methods here as shown in below code.

```
var uniqueListItems  = ListOfLists.SelectMany(l => l)
    .GroupBy(l => l)
    .Select(l => new {Key = l.Key, Count = l.Count()})
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Count);
```

The above code uses `SelectMany` to flatten the list and over the result, the query applies the `GroupBy` to calculate the count.

You can check the sample code at this dotnet fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/VsByaj

Comment: Awesome. I didn't even think of using LINQ. I does make sense, though. I had to make a few adjustments,but this is the solution to the problem.

Comment: @N.MORR `but this is the solution to the problem` because it works, because it's using `linq` or because you don't have anything yet? `I does make sense`, what's makes sense, using `linq`, why does it? If you *have tried* something, why not update your post to include what you have tried and what isn't working so we can actually explain what is wrong and help you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

This should be fairly trivial using a `Dictionary<string, int>` and an enumerator  if you don't want to use LINQ.

Think of something like this:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

var result = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var item in GetAllElements(list1, list2))
{
    if (result.ContainsKey(item)) 
    { 
        result[item] = ++result[item];
    }
    else
    {
        result[item] = 1;
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GetAllElements(params List<string>[] lists)
{
    foreach (var list in lists)
    {
        foreach (var element in list)
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `result[item] = ++result[item];` and `params List<string>[] lists`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto good answer, especially `wrote this while cooking`, impressive!

Comment: Thanks @Çöđěxěŕ :) I'm used to multi-tasking but with a compiler (and unit tests!) at hand haha

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, long> counter = new Dictionary<string, long>();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfLists.Count; i++)
{
    List<string> list = listOfLists[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
    {
        string value = list[j];
        if (counter.ContainsKey(value))
            counter[value]++;
        else
            counter.Add(value, 1);
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
Console.WriteLine($"String abc found {counter["abc"]} times");
```